# Reduce complexity (number of steps till completion) for the following problem. Given N, find how many X satisfy N xor X > N where X ranges from 1 to N

Tags: c

So, i have to solve the following problem. For a given unsigned int N find how many numbers satisfy the following "(X xor N) > N where  1

````
```int main() {
unsigned int n;
int count = 0, temp;
printf("Introduceti un numar natural, pozitiv si mai mic decat 4,294,967,295\n");
scanf("%d", &n);

for (int i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if ((n ^ i) > n) {
        temp = n ^ i;
        //printf("%d \n", temp);
        //printf("%d \n", i);
        count++;
    }
}

printf("%d", count);

system("pause");
return 0;
````

My problem is that i have to reduce the complexity from O(N) to O(LogN) and I can't figure out how. If you could give me an idea of how to do it it'd help me a lot. Thank you in advance.

Comment: [Duplicate.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61351629/reducing-the-complexity-of-a-problem-to-logn)

Comment: @EricPostpischil Thank you for positing the link. I'm sorry for posting a duplicate. I looked around but couldn't find the questiong. Perhaps i should've looked more

Comment: The link helped me solve the problem. Thank you very much.